# Call a function when camera position changes

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

I'm trying to show a UIButton when the distance between the user location and the camera position is greater than 1KM.
How can I achieve this feature?

I tried `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition)` and `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool)` but with no desired results.

Thanks for any further help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
var current: CLLocation?

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

  self.current = locations.last!

}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {

    guard let currentLocation = current else { return } 

    let moved = CLLocation(latitude: position.target.latitude, longitude: position.target.longitude)

    if currentLocation.distance(from: moved) > 1000 {

        self.yourButton.isHidden = false
    } 
    else { //hide it }
}
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me, If I'd like to show a button only when the zoom level is changed how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am using it like this:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
    print("Location: \(location)")

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                          longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                                          zoom: self.zoomLevel)

    if let mapView = self.mapView {

        if mapView.isHidden {
            mapView.isHidden = false
            mapView.camera = camera

        } else {
            mapView.animate(to: camera)
        }
    }
    self.calculateDistance(destiLat: Lat Coordinate, destiLongL: Long Coordinate)
}

    //This function calculates the distance between origin and destination

private func calculateDistance(destiLat: CLLocationDegrees, destiLongL: CLLocationDegrees) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let origin = CLLocation(latitude: self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0, longitude: self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0)
        let destination = CLLocation(latitude: destiLat, longitude: destiLongL)
        let distanceInMeters = origin.distance(from: destination)

        print(distanceInMeters)

        if distanceInMeters.isLessThanOrEqualTo(60) {

           //You are in range of 60 meters
           //Change the distance and show your button here
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know if it is the best way, but it is working for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, also your code is working fine ;)